# ¿Como cerrar un resultSet?

Tags: java

Gente, estoy haciendo un proyecto, y me surgió la siguiente duda. ¿Como cierro un resultSet? o ¿Como hago varios resultSet? El código que tengo es el adjunto. Si no se puede hacer, ¿Que debo hacer para ejecutar varias queries?

```
    public void sendDataToArrayList(){
    Conn connect = new Conn();
    Connection con = connect.conectarMySQL();
            Statement s;
    try {
        String sSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM student st INNER JOIN useru ON est.CI = u.CI ;";
        String sSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM teacher teachr INNER JOIN user u ON prof.CI = u.CI ;";
        String sSQL3 = "SELECT * FROM bilbiotecario biblio INNER JOIN user u ON biblio.CI = u.CI ;";

        s = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = s.executeQuery(sSQL1);
        ResultSet rs2 = s.executeQuery(sSQL2);
        ResultSet rs3 = s.executeQuery(sSQL3);



        while(rs1.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs1);
            close(rs1);
        }

        while(rs2.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs2);
        }

        while(rs3.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs3);
        }


    } catch (SQLException a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        a.printStackTrace();
    }
};
```

Comment: Deberías cerrar el ResultSet, el Statement, y el Connection con sus métodos `close()` en el `finally` de tu bloque try-catch para asegurarte que se cierre tanto si ha habido éxito como si no. Cuando hagas el close() de cada uno de tus objetos, asegurate de que no sean nulos, esto puede pasar si se produce una excepción antes de que se hayan creado.

Comment: ¿Y como quedaría el codigo despues de eso? Si puedes ponerme el codigo te agradezco, porque no termino de entender

Answer (score 4):

Si utilizas  Java 7 o superior lo mejor es utilizar `try-with-resources` que es una forma nueva introducida desde java 7 para evitar todas esas comprobaciones en el `finally` y que algún recurso quede abierto, con `try-with-resources` al final de la ejecución java se encarga de llamar los métodos `close()` de forma segura.
Ademas debes cerrar todos los recursos `Connection - Statement - ResultSet` si lo realizas en el ´finally´ el proceso de cerrar es inverso al de creación `ResultSet - Statement- Connection`

Ejemplo con `try-with-resources`:
La diferencia es que abres un paréntesis en el `try` y declara los recursos que deben de cerrarse al finalizar el bloque `try`.

```
    public void sendDataToArrayList() {
            Conn connect = new Conn();
            String sSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM student st INNER JOIN useru ON est.CI = u.CI ;";

           //try-with-resources recursos a cerrar
            try (
                    Connection con = connect.conectarMySQL();
                    Statement s = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs1 = s.executeQuery(sSQL1);
            ) {

                while (rs1.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs1);
                }
            } catch (SQLException a) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                a.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por esta información

Answer (score 3):

Quizá hay dos cosas interesantes que aclarar para responder a tu respuesta.

### 1. No puedes tener más de un `ResultSet` abierto usando el mismo objeto `Statement`

Lo que haces aquí es una pésima práctica de programación:

```
    ResultSet rs1 = s.executeQuery(sSQL1);
    ResultSet rs2 = s.executeQuery(sSQL2);
    ResultSet rs3 = s.executeQuery(sSQL3);
    //Lectura posterior de rs1, rs2, rs3 es imposible
```

La documentación sobre la [interfaz `Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) es muy clara en ese aspecto:

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a current ResultSet object of the statement
>   if an open one exists.
>
> ---
>
> De manera predeterminada, solo se puede abrir un objeto ResultSet por
>   objeto Statement al mismo tiempo. Por lo tanto, si la lectura de un
>   objeto ResultSet se intercala con la lectura de otro, cada uno debe
>   haber sido generado por diferentes objetos de declaración. Todos los
>   métodos de ejecución en la interfaz de la Declaración cierran
>   implícitamente un objeto ResultSet actual de la instrucción si existe
>   uno abierto.

Si lo que acabamos de leer es cierto, por ejemplo cuando hagas esto: `ResultSet rs2 = s.executeQuery(sSQL2);`, el objeto `rs1` debería cerrarse y cuando intentes leerlo más abajo, tendrás un error.

Si por comodidad quieres usar un solo `Statement`, tienes que irlos leyendo antes de lanzar el siguiente `executeQuery`:

```
    ResultSet rs1 = s.executeQuery(sSQL1);
    //Leer rs1

    ResultSet rs2 = s.executeQuery(sSQL2);
    //Leer rs2

    ResultSet rs3 = s.executeQuery(sSQL3);
    //Leer rs3
```

---

### 2. Los `ResultSet` se cierran con el `Statement`

En caso de no aplicar otro método al objeto `Statement` (que cerraría el anterior `ResultSet` como vimos en (1)), éste **se cierra cuando aplicas el método `close()` al `Statement`**.

Esto viene claramente explicado en [el método `close()` de la interfaz `Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29)

> When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if
>   one exists, is also closed.
>
> ---
>
> Cuando se cierra un objeto de instrucción, su objeto ResultSet actual,
>   si existe, también se cierra.

Y también en la documentación de la interfaz `ResultSet`:

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object
>   that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next
>   result from a sequence of multiple results.
>
> ---
>
> Un objeto ResultSet se cierra automáticamente cuando el objeto
>   Sentencia que lo generó se cierra, se vuelve a ejecutar o se usa para
>   recuperar el siguiente resultado de una secuencia de resultados
>   múltiples.

De ahí concluimos que **no hay necesidad de cerrar el objeto `ResultSet`.** De hecho, si observas [los ejemplos oficiales que explican el funcionamiento de `ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) te darás cuenta que en ninguno de ellos, nunca se cierra el `ResultSet`.

---

### Respuesta a tu pregunta

Como consecuencia de lo dicho en (1) y en (2) podemos responder a tu pregunta diciendo que  sólo tienes que preocuparte por cerrar el objeto que usaste para traer los datos: `Statement, PreparedStatement ...`, y eventualmente la conexión.

Y esto puedes hacerlo de la forma tradicional, en el `finally` del bloque `try ... catch` o usando `try-with-resources` como ya se ha dicho.

Comment: Gracias por esta información